# docker compose and multi-stage dockerfile with nginx

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose

I've run into a problem where my Docker file is running fine outside of Docker compose, but when used in Docker Compose, my Nginx target isn't installed properly in `/usr/share/nginx/html`.

docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3.7"

services:
  web:
    build:
      context: ./web
      dockerfile: Dockerfile-development
    volumes:
      - ./web:/web
      - ./web/node_modules/
    env_file:
      - .env-web
  nginx:
    build:
      context: ./web
      dockerfile: Dockerfile-development
      target: nginx
    volumes:
      - ./web/nginx/default.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d
      - ./web/build:/usr/share/nginx/html
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    depends_on:
      - web
```

dockerfile-development

```
FROM node:9.8.0 as web

ARG APP_ENV=development

WORKDIR /web
COPY package.json /web/package.json
RUN npm install
COPY . /web

RUN npm run build-development

FROM nginx:1.14 as nginx
COPY --from=web /web/build /usr/share/nginx/html
EXPOSE 80
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

So if I build and run `Dockerfile-development` outside of Docker compose everything works and Nginx starts, but if I use `docker-compose up` the images are built and run without errors, but nginx is no where to be found in the container.

**EDIT**
I've figured out that the problem lies in `build-development` which runs `webpack --watch`. It results nginx not running at all. Any way I can have both webpack with the watch flag run in the background, and still have docker move on to building and running the nginx container?

Comment: Note that `docker-compose up` will not rebuild your image if it already exists. What if you explicitly run `docker-compose build`? You will also need to run `docker-compose down` before running `docker-compose up` to remove any existing containers.

Comment: Note that if I grab your examples and `docker-compose build` an image, `nginx` is available exactly as you would expect it to be.

Comment: OK, so now I understand why nginx wasn't working in the first place. My build stage `web` was doing `webpack --watch` which ended up just running in the foreground, never exiting – and nginx was never built. Thanks larsks!